# Apache POI failed to read uploaded docx. Giving error No valid entries or contents found, this is not a valid OOXML (Office Open XML) file

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-poi

I tried to extract uploaded docx file then want to get the paragraphs to be displayed in jasper  report pdf. But when i tried to read the file using apache POI it giving this error :

```
org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.NotOfficeXmlFileException: No valid entries or contents found, this is not a valid OOXML (Office Open XML) file|
```

Don't how to solve this.

This docx file is uploaded then saved in byte array format in database. After get the data, then want to extract it, it didn't work.

Here's my code

```
final var docx = fromByteArray(template.getContent());

// template.getContent() is the byteArray from database
```

then for the ***fromByteArray function*** be like this

```
public static KcDocx fromByteArray(byte[] byteArray) {
    try {
      ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);

      KcDocx var3;
      try {
        XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(inputStream);
        var3 = KcDocx.buildDoc(doc);
      } catch (Throwable var5) {
        try {
          inputStream.close();
        } catch (Throwable var4) {
          var5.addSuppressed(var4);
        }

        throw var5;
      }

      inputStream.close();
      return var3;
    } catch (IOException var6) {
      log.warn("KcDocReaderBytes", var6);
      throw new RuntimeException(var6);
    }
  }
```

then for the ***KCDocx class*** that cointain ***buildDoc function***

```
public class KcDocx {
  @Generated
  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger("WORKBOOK_LOGGER");
  private final List<KcDocxParagraph> paragraphs = new ArrayList();
  private final Set<KcDocxParagraph.Styling> styling = new HashSet();
  private boolean hasBulletOrNumberingList = false;

  public static KcDocx buildDoc(XWPFDocument document) {
    KcDocx doc = new KcDocx();
    doc.hasBulletOrNumberingList = document.getNumbering() != null;
    Stream var10000 = document.getParagraphs().stream().filter((paragraph) -> {
      return StringUtils.isNotEmpty(paragraph.getText());
    });
    Objects.requireNonNull(doc);
    List<KcDocxParagraph> extractedParagraph = (List)var10000.map(doc::extract).collect(Collectors.toList());
    doc.paragraphs.addAll(extractedParagraph);
    log.debug("Extracted document content is empty {} or contains table {}", doc.paragraphs.isEmpty(), !document.getTables().isEmpty());
    return doc;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please have a look at the full stack-trace of the error. I suspect it gets thrown by `XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(inputStream);`. Then `inputStream` seems stream wrong content. Thus `byteArray` contains wrong content. Thus `template.getContent()` gets wrong content from database.

Comment: @AxelRichter This problem is because the byteArray input is corrupted. I tried to use get byte array from database by consuming antother service endpoint through feign client. That feign client giving response not only byte array response but an object that has bytearray property and also other property. I created new endpoint that give byteArray response only then now working perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is because the byteArray input is corrupted. I tried to use get byte array from database by consuming antother service endpoint through feign client. That feign client giving response not only byte array response but an object that has bytearray property and also other property. I created new endpoint that give byteArray response only then now working perfectly